# Passing parameter into a report from a form

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010, parameter-passing

I'm relative new to Access 2010. I built a small CRM/Invoicing database as practice and to use for a while. I used a lot of examples from Northwind to learn from but I don't quite understand passing parameters.

I have two tables for invoice data (index and data), with the PK in the index table being the actual invoice number the customer would see then it's also a FK in the data table. I setup a query and have my report working with all items and totals and have it set on a report. If you call the Report directly, a parameter is asked for the invoice number (the PK in the index table)

What I'm looking to do now is place a button on my invoice form to "View Invoice" and have the parameter of "InvoiceNumber" from the "Invoice_Index" table passed to the report so I'm not prompted to enter it each time I want to view a Invoice/Report from clicking on the "View Invoice" button on my form.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the [DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032%28office.12%29.aspx).  It will allow you to specify a *WhereCondition* when you open the report.  And the *WhereCondition* will operate like a `WHERE` clause in a query.

So if your form has a text box named `txtInvoiceNumber` which contains the `InvoiceNumber` to filter the report on, and if the name of the corresponding field in the report's record source is `InvoiceNumber`, you could use code like this in the click event of the command button on your invoice form.

```vb
Dim strWhereCondition As String
strWhereCondition = "InvoiceNumber = " & Me.txtInvoiceNumber
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", , , strWhereCondition
```

That should work if `InvoiceNumber` is numeric data type.  If it's actually text data type, add quotes around `Me.txtInvoiceNumber` when you build the *WhereCondition*.

```vb
strWhereCondition = "InvoiceNumber = '" & Me.txtInvoiceNumber & "'"
```

(This suggestion assumes you will revise the query used by the report to eliminate the existing parameter.)

Comment: The field name on the form and report is "InvoiceNumber", I changed your code above to reflect this but got End of Statement errors. The field is a autonumber.

Comment: I finally noticed I left out two critical ampersands (`&`).  Sorry if the correction is too late to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings, you need to use the `&` symbol between the parts to be put together.  You can also combine all of these lines into one line.  Try to explicitly state which property you want, rather than relying on default properties.

```
Me.OpenReport "YourReportName", , , "InvoiceNumber = " & Me.txtInvoiceNumber.Value
```